# How to prove the divergence of $\zeta(s)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, riemann-zeta

I was hoping someone could give me a proof of the divergence of the zeta series ($\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$) for $0<\Re(s)\leq1$. I understand how to prove the divergence if $s\in\mathbb{R}$, however I am not sure about how to approach this with complex values of $s$.

Comment: $\zeta(s)$ **is not** divergent on the whole line $\text{Re}(s)=1$. It just has a simple pole at $s=1$. The statement equivalent to the PNT is that $\zeta(s)$ is non-vanishing over $\text{Re}(s)=1$.

Comment: To study the behaviour of $\zeta(s)$ on the line $\text{Re}(s)=1$ you may use the integral representation $$\zeta(s)=\frac{2^s}{\Gamma(s)(2^s-2)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1}\,dx $$ which holds for any $s$ such that $\text{Re}(s)>0$.

Comment: If you are asking about the divergence of the zeta **series** you should make that explicit.

Comment: After this change, it is a good question.

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly to be in sync with your question. Did you really need to repost the same question, instead of trying to read my solution?

Comment: @1707107 I'm so sorry about that! I know that I shouldn't have done that and at the time I didn't realize, but thanks for pointing it out. I'll make sure not to do that in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sigma=\mathfrak{R}(s)\leq 0$, then by the [Test for Divergence](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/divergence.html), we have divergence of the zeta series.

If $s=1$, then the zeta series is just the harmonic series. Thus, it diverges.

If $0<\sigma \leq 1$ and $s\neq 1$,

We apply partial summation, which is also integration by part for Stieltjes integrals, to the partial sum of the zeta series. Let $\{t\}=t-\lfloor t\rfloor$ be the fractional part of $t$. If $N\geq 2$, $0<\sigma\leq 1$ and $s=\sigma+it\neq 1$, then

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\leq N} \frac1{n^s} &= \int_{1-}^N \frac{d\lfloor t\rfloor}{t^s}\\
&=\frac{\lfloor t \rfloor}{t^s}\Bigg\vert_{1-}^N + s\int_{1-}^N \frac{\lfloor t \rfloor}{t^{s+1}} dt\\
&=\frac{t-\{ t\} }{t^s}\Bigg\vert_{1-}^N + s\int_{1-}^N \frac{t-\{t\}}{t^{s+1}} dt\\
&=N^{1-s}+O\left(\frac 1{N^{\sigma}}\right)+ \frac{st^{1-s}}{1-s}\Bigg\vert_{1-}^N -s\int_1^N \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}}dt\\
&=N^{1-s}+O\left(\frac1{N^{\sigma}}\right)+\frac s{1-s} N^{1-s}+\frac s{s-1}-s\int_1^N \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}} dt\\
&=N^{1-s}+\frac s{1-s} N^{1-s}+\frac s{s-1}-s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}} dt+O\left(\frac{1+|s|/\sigma}{N^{\sigma}}\right).
\end{align}
$$
The expression below is an analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$ to $\sigma>0$. 
$$
\zeta(s)=\frac s{s-1}-s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}} dt.
$$
Thus, we have for $0<\sigma\leq 1$, 
$$
\sum_{n\leq N}\frac1{n^s} = \frac {N^{1-s}}{1-s}  + \zeta(s) + O\left( \frac{1+|s|/\sigma}{N^{\sigma}}\right).
$$

For $0<\sigma<1$, we have 
$$
\left|\sum_{n\leq N}\frac1{n^s}\right|\geq \frac{N^{1-\sigma}}{|1-s|}-|\zeta(s)|+O\left( \frac{1+|s|/\sigma}{N^{\sigma}}\right)\rightarrow \infty \ \ \textrm{ as }\  N\rightarrow\infty.
$$
. Thus, the zeta series diverges in this case, and the partial sums are unbounded.

With $\sigma =1$, $t\neq 0$, $s=1+it$, we have
$$
\sum_{n\leq N} \frac 1{n^{1+it}} = \frac{N^{-it}}{-it} + \zeta(1+it) +O\left(\frac {1+|t|}N\right).
$$

The $N$-th partial sum of the zeta series at $s=1+it$ with $t\neq 0$, shows an oscillating behavior due to $N^{-it}=\exp(-it \log N)$. The partial sums are bounded. Therefore, the zeta series diverges at $s=1+it$.

Comment: I hope these questions don't sound stupid, but 1) Why is the integral not $\int_{1-}^{N}\frac{dt}{\{t\}^s}$? 2) Where does the big O come from in lines 4 and 6 of the proof?

Comment: 1) There is no way $\{t\}$ can go to the denominator. 2) Line4: it comes from $\{t\}/t^s$ at $t=N$, Line 6: it comes from $$s\int_N^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}} dt$$

Comment: My suggestion for you before reading this, is that study Stieltjes integral first.

Comment: Hope I'm not proving to be bothersome, but one last question: Why is $+O\left(\frac{1}{N^\sigma}\right)$ not negative?

Comment: In the big oh notation, the sign in front of it is not relevant. But, + is preferred way of writing. You can search "big oh notation" and read relevant definition and properties.

Comment: You say that for $\sigma\leq0$ the divergence test is sufficient, but that test is only for real values, not complex. What am I missing?

Comment: @Tariq It also works for complex.