# How to show $\sum 1/n^s$ doesn't converge for $0\leq Re(s) \leq 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, power-series, riemann-zeta

There are many sources which show fairly easily that for $\sum 1/n^s$ with complex $s$:

- the infinite sum converges for $Re(s)>1$
- the infinite sum diverges for $Re(s)<0$

However I can't find accessible proofs that show:

- the infinite sum diverges for $0 \leq Re(s)<1$
- the infinite sum doesn't converge (oscillates?) for $Re(s)=1$ and $s\neq 1$

To be clear, I am not asking about the analytic continuation of the Riemann Zeta function, only the power series $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^s$.

---

Notes:

I have asked a related question ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142510/proofs-of-converge-of-zeta-sigmait-dont-seem-to-show-divergence-for-sig)) which is not as precise as this one. That one wasn't answered fully.

I have searched stack exchange and math overflow (and academic papers/notes) and have not found accessible proofs. Where this question is discussed the commentary glosses over the working.

Comment: A standard property of Dirichlet series (it is in Apostol and many other books on analytic number theory) is that if $\sum a_n/n^s$ converges at the complex number $s_0$ then $\sum a_n/n^s$ converges on the open half-plane $\{s : {\rm Re}(s) > {\rm Re}(s_0)\}$. Therefore divergence at a point $s$ implies divergence at $s_0$ when ${\rm Re}(s_0) < {\rm Re}(s)$.  Apply this with $s = 1$ and ${\rm Re}(s_0) < 1$. Divergence (really, oscillation) if ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$  and $s \not = 1$ requires a different argument and can be done with partial summation.  Look in textbooks on analytic number theory.

Comment: Thanks @KCd for your prompt. I have be re-reading the relevant sections from Apostol, Stopple, Tanenbaum and Edwards and I still need a bit of help (apologies, I'm not a trained mathematician). From Apostol I can see theorems that say a Dirichlet series converges at $\sigma>\sigma_a$ if it converges at $\sigma_a$. The logical equivalent is that it diverges at $\sigma<\sigma_b$ if it diverges at $\sigma_b$. However I couldn't find an explicit proof the Riemann Zeta series actually diverges for any $0<\sigma<1$. Here $\sigma=Re(s)$.  Comment 1/2

Comment: I guess it would be sufficient to show the series diverges at $s=1+0i$. Can anyone confirm this is a correct statement, and that therefore there is no need to prove the series diverges at any point on the line $1+it$ because proving it as $s=1+0i$ is sufficient? Any pointers very welcome. By way of giving back I will be blogging and creating videos of my learning in case it helps others at https://fromprimestoriemann.blogspot.com. Comment 2/2

Comment: You can’t find a proof that $\sum_{n\geq 1} 1/n$ diverges?

Comment: @kcd ..Edited original comment

Comment: The divergence at $s=1$ implies divergence when ${\rm Re}(s) < 1$. It does *not* imply divergence (really, oscillatory behavior) elsewhere on the line ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$. For that another argument is needed and it typically is handled using partial summation.

Comment: For other readers, the answer here looks helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2700579/how-to-prove-the-divergence-of-zetas